# How to load Native Library on EMR(AWS) Spark Hadoop Cluster for Java

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I'm new to EMR and Spark Hadoop Cluster.
I have to load Native **abcd_linux.so** library on runtime for my executable xyz_spark.jar. All the JARs, Native library and bootstrap files are uploaded to s3 bucket(**spark-bucket**) like below:-

```
s3://spark-bucket/bootstrap/xyz_spark.jar
s3://spark-bucket/bootstrap/bootstrap_action.sh
s3://spark-bucket/bootstrap/linux/abcd_linux.so
```

where **bootstrap_action.sh** is like

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/hadoop/linux
aws s3 cp s3://spark-bucket/bootstrap/ /home/hadoop --recursive
ls -l /home/hadoop
```

And class/code which loading **abcd_linux.so** is like below

```
val os = System.getProperty("os.name")
logger.info("Current OS is "+os)
println("Current OS is "+os)
if(os.toLowerCase().contains("windows")){
  System.loadLibrary("abcd_win")
}else{
  System.loadLibrary("abcd_linux")
}
```

And JAVA_OPTIONS being passed to app like below:-

```
"--driver-java-options", "-Dcontext=dev/app_dev_steps.json -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/hadoop/log4j.xml -DLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/hadoop/linux",
```

But library is not getting loaded and not able to find any proper documentation steps to load native library.